# Unknown receiver FBSDKRequestConnection using Parse and Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, sdk

I am working on an app that offers Facebook login functionality. When I try to call `FBSDKRequestConnection`, I am getting the error outlined in the title.

My import statements are as follows:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

I am calling the following code:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController * __nonnull)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser * __nonnull)user {
    [FBSDKRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [self facebookRequestDidLoad:result];
        }
        else {
            [self showErrorAndLogout];
        }
    }];
}
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using `FBSDKGraphRequest` appears to have resolved the issue.